# How to use Backbone.Marionette.ItemView with Mustache

Tags: backbone.js, mustache, marionette

The following code works fine using `Backbone.Marionette.ItemView` but not `Mustache`.

[Backbone.Marionette.ItemView - no Mustache](http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/me4NK/)

I would like to use the same code but loading the template varaible using `Mustache`.

Here is my code:

[Backbone.Marionette.ItemView - with Mustache](http://jsfiddle.net/me4NK/76/)

Any idea why [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/me4NK/76/) does not work and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marionette assumes the use of UnderscoreJS templates by default. Simply replacing the `template` configuration for a view isn't enough. You also need to replace how the rendering process works.

In your simple example, you only need to override the `Marionette.Renderer.render` function to call Mustache, and then set the `template` of your views to the string template that you want:

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data){
  return Mustache.to_html(template, data);
}

var rowTemplate = '{{ username }}{{ fullname }}';

// A Grid Row
var GridRow = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: rowTemplate,
    tagName: "tr"
});
```

Note that your JSFiddle still won't work even when you put this code in place, because the `GridView` is still using a jQuery selector/string as the `template` attribute. You'll need to replace this with the same type of `template` function to return mustache.

http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/d7qDz/

Comment: Looking at the source (http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-115) it seems to me that it should be enough to override `Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate`: http://jsfiddle.net/me4NK/78/ What is more appropriate way?

Comment: it depends on whether or not you are using the default behavior of selecting a template from the DOM, or providing the template as a raw string. In the case of this question, the template is a raw string, so overriding `Renderer.render` is more appropriate. If the template is a DOM `<script>` tag, though, then the TemplateCache `compileTemplate` function would be the correct choice.

Comment: Which is better to use with iCanHaz which holds it templates in index.html? Please help if you can, here's more detail -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640168/integrating-icanhaz-and-marionette

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to update the answer here a bit as I was just struggling with this, and I was using this answer as a reference.

Here are my findings:

The answer here is a bit out of date with the current version of **Mustache** (which is understandable as it's pretty old)

- **Mustache.to_html** is now deprecated, but still exists as a simple wrapper around **Mustache.render** for backwards compat. [Check out this link](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L550-L559).

Additionally, I found overriding **Marionette.Renderer.render**, as in the accepted answer above, completely bypasses the **Marionette.TemplateCache** layer which may not be the desired behavior.

Here's the source for the **Marionette.Renderer.render** method:

```
render: function(template, data){

  if (!template) {
    var error = new Error("Cannot render the template since it's false, null or undefined.");
    error.name = "TemplateNotFoundError";
    throw error;
  }

  var templateFunc;
  if (typeof template === "function"){
    templateFunc = template;
  } else {
    templateFunc = Marionette.TemplateCache.get(template);
  }

  return templateFunc(data);
}
```

<sup>[Source](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.renderer.js#L12-L29)</sup>

As you can see it accesses the **Marionette.TemplateCache.get** method and the above answer does nothing to maintain that functionality.

Now to get to my solve (note: the above answer is not wrong necessarily; this is just my approach to maintain the **Marionette.TemplateCache** layer):

As the comments suggest above, override **compileTemplate** instead:

```
Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate = function(rawTemplate) {

    // Mustache.parse will not return anything useful (returns an array)
    // The render function from Marionette.Renderer.render expects a function
    // so instead pass a partial of Mustache.render 
    // with rawTemplate as the initial parameter.

    // Additionally Mustache.compile no longer exists so we must use parse.
    Mustache.parse(rawTemplate);
    return _.partial(Mustache.render, rawTemplate);
};
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle as proof](http://jsfiddle.net/aubricus/ktG52/).

In the fiddle, I've also overridden **Marionette.TemplateCache.loadTemplate** to demonstrate that it's only called once. The body of the function only adds some debug output and then re-implements most of the original functionality (minus error handling).